# DB2 SQL Developer Script to find column with Maximum Value or equal value and create another column with labels

Tags: sql, db2

I am having a DB2 Sql Developer table with the folloing structure:

```
Customer_id | Electric Bill | water Bill | gas Bill | Phone Bill | Airtime Bill |
XXXXXYYYYY             45%           20%        15%         10%            10%
ZZZZZTTTTT             10%           60%        4%           6%            20%
```

My Goal is to have a final colmn that will tell me the preferred service per customer:

```
Customer_id | Electric Bill | water Bill | gas Bill | Phone Bill | Airtime Bill |Peferred Service|
XXXXXYYYYY             45%           20%        15%         10%            10%    Electric Bill
ZZZZZTTTTT             10%           60%        4%           6%            20%    Water Bill
```

Assume that the table has more than 2 Mil data and it is dynamic:

1. how can I do this without doing it manually
2. In case where service tie to each other like 50% and 50%, I need to make sure they are all appear in the preferred service column like 'Electric and water Bill'

NOTE:

I am using DB2 SQL Developer.

Comment: Why are the numbers red? Is the data stored really with "%"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be one solution:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT Customer_id, Electric_Bill, Water_Bill,  Gas_Bill,  Phone_Bill, Airtime_Bill
     , greatest(Electric_Bill, Water_Bill,  Gas_Bill,  Phone_Bill, Airtime_Bill) AS greatest
     , CASE WHEN Electric_Bill = greatest(Electric_Bill, water_Bill,  gas_Bill,  Phone_Bill, Airtime_Bill) THEN 'Electric_Bill' ELSE '' END AS Electric_Bill_result
     , CASE WHEN water_Bill = greatest(Electric_Bill, water_Bill,  gas_Bill,  Phone_Bill, Airtime_Bill) THEN 'Water_Bill' ELSE '' END AS water_Bill_result
     , CASE WHEN gas_Bill = greatest(Electric_Bill, water_Bill,  gas_Bill,  Phone_Bill, Airtime_Bill) THEN 'Gas_Bill' ELSE '' END AS gas_Bill_result
     , CASE WHEN Phone_Bill = greatest(Electric_Bill, water_Bill,  gas_Bill,  Phone_Bill, Airtime_Bill) THEN 'Phone_Bill' ELSE '' END AS Phone_Bill_result
     , CASE WHEN Airtime_Bill = greatest(Electric_Bill, water_Bill,  gas_Bill,  Phone_Bill, Airtime_Bill) THEN 'Airtime_Bill' ELSE '' END AS Airtime_Bill_result     
  FROM bill
)
SELECT Customer_id, Electric_Bill, water_Bill,  gas_Bill,  Phone_Bill, Airtime_Bill
      , Trim(Electric_Bill_result || ' ' || Water_Bill_result || ' ' || Gas_Bill_result || ' ' || Phone_Bill_result || ' ' || Airtime_Bill_result) AS Peferred_Service
  FROM CTE
```

If your data contains the "%" or your really want a and between multiple identical greatest values you have to add some "cosmetics"

Comment: This works fine on my side, Thanks!

Comment: Now my only worry is, Assume we are working with High dimension data with more than let say 100 column, how can we make a much better efficient and Dynamic script, which requires less manual input of column... something like pivoting?

Comment: For pivoting table data you will find lots of answers in this forum - these questions have been asked many times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option.

Sample data:

```
CUSTOMER_ID  ELECTRIC_BILL WATER_BILL   GAS_BILL PHONE_BILL AIRTIME_BILL
------------ ------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------
t                       10         60          4          6           20
x                       30         10         30         20           10
y                       45         20         15         10           10
```

Query uses two subqueries:

- the first utilizes the `greatest` function to find which bill amount is the greatest for each customer
- another one makes a *table* of all bills so that you could join every amount to previously found greatest value

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xgrbuxnV) is here.

Query:

```
select t.*,
  listagg(uni.what, ', ') within group (order by uni.what) what
from test t 
join (select customer_id, greatest(electric_bill, water_bill, gas_bill, phone_bill, airtime_bill) grt
      from test
     ) a on a.customer_id = t.customer_id
join (select electric_bill as bill, 'electric' what from test union all
      select water_bill           , 'water'         from test union all
      select gas_bill             , 'gas'           from test union all
      select phone_bill           , 'phone'         from test union all
      select airtime_bill         , 'airtime'       from test
     ) uni on uni.bill = a.grt
group by t.customer_id, t.electric_bill, t.water_bill, t.gas_bill, t.phone_bill, t.airtime_bill
order by t.customer_id;
```

Result:

```
CUSTOMER_ID  ELECTRIC_BILL WATER_BILL   GAS_BILL PHONE_BILL AIRTIME_BILL WHAT
------------ ------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------ ----------------
t                       10         60          4          6           20 water
x                       30         10         30         20           10 electric, gas
y                       45         20         15         10           10 electric
```

Comment: Let me try this, I will give feedback

Comment: On my side this solution takes long time to get executed, so I cant confirm

Comment: Well, it works on a small dataset (as demonstrated). Never mind, I'm glad you got the answer (the one Michael posted) so - everything is just fine. Thank you for the feedback, though!